# SKAudioNode problem after App going down, restart, is this a bug?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaudionode

I have a problem with the SKAudioNode. The game ends with the Home Button. An audio file will be played.

When I return, the audio file will continue to play.

I want to stop it.

I have tried many things but without success.

`self.AudioNodeSet.removeFromParent()` // does not work

`self.AudioNodeSet.run(SKAction.stop())` // does not work either

Can anyone help me?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {  
 var AudioNodeSet = SKAudioNode()  
     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {  
     self.addChild(AudioNodeSet) // Audio Node  
        AudioNodeSet.name = "AudioNodeSet"  
......  

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {  
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.window!.bounds)  
        imageView.tag = 101  
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white  
        //imageView.contentMode = .center  
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill  
        let pic = UIImage(named: "Start Page.jpg") // Overwrite Return Scene  
        imageView.image = pic  
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews.last?.addSubview(imageView)  
    }  

........  

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {  

        scene?.size = CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080)  
        scene?.backgroundColor = .black   
        scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill   

        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default  
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)  
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToForeground), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)  
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillTerminate), name: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification, object: nil)  

.........  

@objc func appMovedToForeground() {  

        print("applicationWillResignActive -> appMovedToForeground")  
        self.AudioNodeSet.run(SKAction.stop()) // not work!  
        self.AudioNodeSet.removeFromParent() // second try -> not work!
```

This code is executed when the game continues.

The rest of the audio file can then be heard.

Comment: Have you tried pausing the sound in your applicationWillResignActive() call ?

Comment: AudioNodeSet.isHidden = true or
AudioNodeSet.isPaused = true 
has no effect

Comment: But with the query AudioNodeSet.hasActions() I see if audio is available or not.